Heroku (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/job-helper.git', python, Flask, spacy, nltk
I am getting a flask app deployment on Heroku, It is a python app using tensor flow, spacy, nltk packages.
The heorku cli gives the error but it is not clear what is the issue, I am not able to identify if the failure occured when the app is running or installing the packages
Complete log:
'''
(project_env) karthikvibuthi@Karthiks-MacBook-Air Job-Helper % git push heroku main           
Enumerating objects: 150, done.
Counting objects: 100% (150/150), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects: 100% (150/150), 6.31 MiB | 14.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 150 (delta 72), reused 136 (delta 66), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Updated 23 paths from 948ccb0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-24 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python 3.10 specified in runtime.txt
remote: -----> Installing Python 3.10.15
remote: -----> Installing pip 24.0, setuptools 70.3.0 and wheel 0.44.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
remote:        Collecting en_core_web_sm@ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.8.0/en_core_web_sm-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=1932429db727d4bff3deed6b34cfc05df17794f4a52eeb26cf8928f7c1a0fb85 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.8.0/en_core_web_sm-3.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (12.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting annotated-types==0.7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading annotated_types-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting blinker==1.9.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading blinker-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting blis==1.0.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading blis-1.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting catalogue==2.0.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading catalogue-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2024.8.30 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer==3.4.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-3.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (34 kB)
remote:        Collecting click==8.1.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting cloudpathlib==0.20.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading cloudpathlib-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (14 kB)
remote:        Collecting confection==0.1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading confection-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting cymem==2.0.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading cymem-2.0.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting Cython==3.0.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading Cython-3.0.11-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting filelock==3.16.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading filelock-3.16.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==3.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Downloading flask-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask-Cors==5.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 15))
remote:          Downloading Flask_Cors-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting fsspec==2024.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading fsspec-2024.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==23.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-23.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting huggingface-hub==0.26.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:          Downloading huggingface_hub-0.26.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==3.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading idna-3.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==2.2.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 20))
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==3.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 21))
remote:          Downloading jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting joblib==1.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 22))
remote:          Downloading joblib-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting langcodes==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 23))
remote:          Downloading langcodes-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (29 kB)
remote:        Collecting language_data==1.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 24))
remote:          Downloading language_data-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
remote:        Collecting marisa-trie==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 25))
remote:          Downloading marisa_trie-1.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting markdown-it-py==3.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 26))
remote:          Downloading markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==3.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 27))
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-3.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting mdurl==0.1.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 28))
remote:          Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting mpmath==1.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 29))
remote:          Downloading mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting murmurhash==1.0.10 (from -r requirements.txt (line 30))
remote:          Downloading murmurhash-1.0.10-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting networkx==3.4.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 31))
remote:          Downloading networkx-3.4.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
remote:        Collecting nltk==3.9.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 32))
remote:          Downloading nltk-3.9.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting numpy==2.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 33))
remote:          Downloading numpy-2.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
remote:        Collecting packaging==24.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 34))
remote:          Downloading packaging-24.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting pandas==2.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 35))
remote:          Downloading pandas-2.2.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (89 kB)
remote:        Collecting pillow==11.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 36))
remote:          Downloading pillow-11.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.1 kB)
remote:        Collecting plac==1.4.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 37))
remote:          Downloading plac-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting preshed==3.0.9 (from -r requirements.txt (line 38))
remote:          Downloading preshed-3.0.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting pydantic==2.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 39))
remote:          Downloading pydantic-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (167 kB)
remote:        Collecting pydantic_core==2.27.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 40))
remote:          Downloading pydantic_core-2.27.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting Pygments==2.18.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 41))
remote:          Downloading pygments-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyspellchecker==0.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 42))
remote:          Downloading pyspellchecker-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 43))
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2024.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 44))
remote:          Downloading pytz-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
remote:        Collecting PyYAML==6.0.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 45))
remote:          Downloading PyYAML-6.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (2.1 kB)
remote:        Collecting regex==2024.11.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 46))
remote:          Downloading regex-2024.11.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (40 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.32.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 47))
remote:          Downloading requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting rich==13.9.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 48))
remote:          Downloading rich-13.9.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting safetensors==0.4.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 49))
remote:          Downloading safetensors-0.4.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (3.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting scikit-learn==1.5.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 50))
remote:          Downloading scikit_learn-1.5.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting scipy==1.14.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 51))
remote:          Downloading scipy-1.14.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (60 kB)
remote:        Collecting sentence-transformers==3.3.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 52))
remote:          Downloading sentence_transformers-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting shellingham==1.5.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 53))
remote:          Downloading shellingham-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.16.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 54))
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting smart-open==7.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 55))
remote:          Downloading smart_open-7.0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (24 kB)
remote:        Collecting spacy==3.8.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 56))
remote:          Downloading spacy-3.8.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (27 kB)
remote:        Collecting spacy-legacy==3.0.12 (from -r requirements.txt (line 57))
remote:          Downloading spacy_legacy-3.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting spacy-loggers==1.0.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 58))
remote:          Downloading spacy_loggers-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting srsly==2.4.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 59))
remote:          Downloading srsly-2.4.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
remote:        Collecting sympy==1.13.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 60))
remote:          Downloading sympy-1.13.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
remote:        Collecting thinc==8.3.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 61))
remote:          Downloading thinc-8.3.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting threadpoolctl==3.5.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 62))
remote:          Downloading threadpoolctl-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
remote:        Collecting tika==2.6.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 63))
remote:          Downloading tika-2.6.0.tar.gz (27 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting tokenizers==0.20.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 64))
remote:          Downloading tokenizers-0.20.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting torch==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading torch-2.2.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (26 kB)
remote:        Collecting tqdm==4.67.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 66))
remote:          Downloading tqdm-4.67.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
remote:        Collecting transformers==4.46.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 67))
remote:          Downloading transformers-4.46.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (44 kB)
remote:        Collecting typer==0.13.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 68))
remote:          Downloading typer-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting typing_extensions==4.12.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 69))
remote:          Downloading typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting tzdata==2024.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 70))
remote:          Downloading tzdata-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3==2.2.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 71))
remote:          Downloading urllib3-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting wasabi==1.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 72))
remote:          Downloading wasabi-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (28 kB)
remote:        Collecting weasel==0.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 73))
remote:          Downloading weasel-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==3.1.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 74))
remote:          Downloading werkzeug-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting wrapt==1.16.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 75))
remote:          Downloading wrapt-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.1.105 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.1.105 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.1.105 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.2.26 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.1.3.1 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.2.54 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu12-11.0.2.54-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.2.106 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_curand_cu12-10.3.2.106-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.4.5.107 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu12-11.4.5.107-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.1.0.106 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_cusparse_cu12-12.1.0.106-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.19.3 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu12-2.19.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-nvtx-cu12==12.1.105 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_nvtx_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting triton==2.2.0 (from torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading triton-2.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12 (from nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.4.5.107->torch==2.2.2->-r requirements.txt (line 65))
remote:          Downloading nvidia_nvjitlink_cu12-12.6.85-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
remote:        Downloading annotated_types-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        Downloading blinker-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
remote:        Downloading blis-1.0.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (9.2 MB)
remote:        Downloading catalogue-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Downloading certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl (167 kB)
remote:        Downloading charset_normalizer-3.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (144 kB)
remote:        Downloading click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Downloading cloudpathlib-0.20.0-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
remote:        Downloading confection-0.1.5-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
remote:        Downloading cymem-2.0.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (46 kB)
remote:        Downloading Cython-3.0.11-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.6 MB)
remote:        Downloading filelock-3.16.1-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Downloading flask-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
remote:        Downloading Flask_Cors-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
remote:        Downloading fsspec-2024.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
remote:        Downloading gunicorn-23.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (85 kB)
remote:        Downloading huggingface_hub-0.26.2-py3-none-any.whl (447 kB)
remote:        Downloading idna-3.10-py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
remote:        Downloading itsdangerous-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Downloading jinja2-3.1.4-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Downloading joblib-1.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (301 kB)
remote:        Downloading langcodes-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (182 kB)
remote:        Downloading language_data-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.4 MB)
remote:        Downloading marisa_trie-1.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
remote:        Downloading markdown_it_py-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (87 kB)
remote:        Downloading MarkupSafe-3.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (20 kB)
remote:        Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)
remote:        Downloading mpmath-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (536 kB)
remote:        Downloading murmurhash-1.0.10-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (29 kB)
remote:        Downloading networkx-3.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
remote:        Downloading nltk-3.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
remote:        Downloading numpy-2.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (19.5 MB)
remote:        Downloading packaging-24.2-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
remote:        Downloading pandas-2.2.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.1 MB)
remote:        Downloading pillow-11.0.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.4 MB)
remote:        Downloading plac-1.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
remote:        Downloading preshed-3.0.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (156 kB)
remote:        Downloading pydantic-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (454 kB)
remote:        Downloading pydantic_core-2.27.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (2.1 MB)
remote:        Downloading pygments-2.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
remote:        Downloading pyspellchecker-0.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.8 MB)
remote:        Downloading python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
remote:        Downloading pytz-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (508 kB)
remote:        Downloading PyYAML-6.0.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (751 kB)
remote:        Downloading regex-2024.11.6-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (781 kB)
remote:        Downloading requests-2.32.3-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
remote:        Downloading rich-13.9.4-py3-none-any.whl (242 kB)
remote:        Downloading safetensors-0.4.5-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (435 kB)
remote:        Downloading scikit_learn-1.5.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (13.3 MB)
remote:        Downloading scipy-1.14.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (41.2 MB)
remote:        Downloading sentence_transformers-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (268 kB)
remote:        Downloading shellingham-1.5.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
remote:        Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Downloading smart_open-7.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
remote:        Downloading spacy-3.8.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (29.1 MB)
remote:        Downloading spacy_legacy-3.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
remote:        Downloading spacy_loggers-1.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
remote:        Downloading srsly-2.4.8-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (493 kB)
remote:        Downloading sympy-1.13.3-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 MB)
remote:        Downloading thinc-8.3.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.7 MB)
remote:        Downloading threadpoolctl-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Downloading tokenizers-0.20.3-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
remote:        Downloading torch-2.2.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB)
remote:        Downloading tqdm-4.67.0-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
remote:        Downloading transformers-4.46.3-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 MB)
remote:        Downloading typer-0.13.1-py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
remote:        Downloading typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
remote:        Downloading tzdata-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (346 kB)
remote:        Downloading urllib3-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (126 kB)
remote:        Downloading wasabi-1.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
remote:        Downloading weasel-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
remote:        Downloading werkzeug-3.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (224 kB)
remote:        Downloading wrapt-1.16.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (80 kB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (410.6 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (14.1 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (23.7 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (823 kB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.2.26-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (731.7 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu12-11.0.2.54-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (121.6 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_curand_cu12-10.3.2.106-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (56.5 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu12-11.4.5.107-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (124.2 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_cusparse_cu12-12.1.0.106-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (196.0 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_nccl_cu12-2.19.3-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (166.0 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_nvtx_cu12-12.1.105-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (99 kB)
remote:        Downloading triton-2.2.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (167.9 MB)
remote:        Downloading nvidia_nvjitlink_cu12-12.6.85-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.whl (19.7 MB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: tika
remote:          Building wheel for tika (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for tika (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for tika: filename=tika-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl size=32623 sha256=89c8cf6fa483bb9f9a3866c515c1e9e861db53f5ed9333c7d6f968c8a6928d3c
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-7xahppo1/wheels/5f/71/c7/b757709531121b1700cffda5b6b0d4aad095fb507ec84316d0
remote:        Successfully built tika
remote:        Installing collected packages: pytz, plac, mpmath, en_core_web_sm, cymem, wrapt, wasabi, urllib3, tzdata, typing_extensions, tqdm, threadpoolctl, sympy, spacy-loggers, spacy-legacy, six, shellingham, safetensors, regex, PyYAML, pyspellchecker, Pygments, pillow, packaging, nvidia-nvtx-cu12, nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12, nvidia-nccl-cu12, nvidia-curand-cu12, nvidia-cufft-cu12, nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12, nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12, nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12, nvidia-cublas-cu12, numpy, networkx, murmurhash, mdurl, MarkupSafe, marisa-trie, joblib, itsdangerous, idna, fsspec, filelock, Cython, click, charset-normalizer, certifi, catalogue, blinker, annotated-types, Werkzeug, triton, srsly, smart-open, scipy, requests, python-dateutil, pydantic_core, preshed, nvidia-cusparse-cu12, nvidia-cudnn-cu12, nltk, markdown-it-py, language_data, Jinja2, gunicorn, cloudpathlib, blis, tika, scikit-learn, rich, pydantic, pandas, nvidia-cusolver-cu12, langcodes, huggingface-hub, Flask, typer, torch, tokenizers, Flask-Cors, confection, weasel, transformers, thinc, spacy, sentence-transformers
remote: -----> Downloading NLTK corpora...
remote: -----> Downloading NLTK packages: punkt wordnet stopwords omw-1.4 averaged_perceptron_tagger
remote:        /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/runpy.py:126: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
remote:          warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
remote:        [nltk_data] Downloading package punkt to
remote:        [nltk_data]     /app/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
remote:        [nltk_data]   Unzipping tokenizers/punkt.zip.
remote:        [nltk_data] Downloading package wordnet to
remote:        [nltk_data]     /app/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
remote:        [nltk_data] Downloading package stopwords to
remote:        [nltk_data]     /app/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
remote:        [nltk_data]   Unzipping corpora/stopwords.zip.
remote:        [nltk_data] Downloading package omw-1.4 to
remote:        [nltk_data]     /app/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
remote:        [nltk_data] Downloading package averaged_perceptron_tagger to
remote:        [nltk_data]     /app/.heroku/python/nltk_data...
remote:        [nltk_data]   Unzipping taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger.zip.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to job-helper.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/job-helper.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/job-helper.git'
'''

Repo:
https://github.com/karthikvibuthi/Job-Helper
